# Angular.Js - Ionic Mobile App / Identify the landing page?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, authentication, ionic-framework

I am developing an application with Angularjs library on Cordova platform. I want to specify the application's landing page. But this landing page will be opened only once. In most of the examples I have found, in the program is directed back to this page does not reach the landing page.

They provide it with `$urlrouterprovider.otherwise` method.  For example;

https://github.com/sibin-p/sp-ionic_login/blob/master/ionic_login_simple/www/js/app.js

Is there an example of a source of this problem? Example applications or code?

Answer (score 0):

I would set a value into localStorage and then conditionally set the otherwise.

```
if (localStorage.getItem('landing') === null) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('landing');
} else {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}
```

Then in your `landing` controller, you would set the localStorage value.

```
localStorage.setItem('landing', 'true');
```

So the first time the app loads, the `landing` controller will add the value to localStorage, and any additional reloads will load that value and set the otherwise to `home`.